# My custom JMeter listener cannot work in Linux

Tags: linux, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to save the information about sampleResult into MySQL. So I write my own listener named Performance Logger. And it can work well on my Windows. But when I move the same JMeter Script into Linux, it failed. Here are some code about my custom listener.

```
LoggerVisualizer.class

public class LoggerVisualizer extends AbstractVisualizer {
private PerformanceResultCollector collector;
public LoggerVisualizer() {
    super();
    initConfiguration();
}
private void initConfiguration() {
    // some code
}
@Override
public void clearData() {
    //some codes

}
public String getStaticLabel() {
    return "Performance Logger";
}

public String getLabelResource(){
    return "Performance Logger";
}

@Override
public void add(SampleResult sampleResult) {

}

public TestElement createTestElement() {
    if (collector == null) {
        collector = new PerformanceResultCollector();
    }
    modifyTestElement(collector);
    return collector;
}
}
```

PerformanceResultCollector.class

```
public class PerformanceResultCollector extends ResultCollector implements Serializable {    
CustomCollector collector;

public PerformanceResultCollector() {    
    log.info("construct performance collector")
    collector = new CustomCollector();

}
@Override
public void sampleOccurred(SampleEvent e) {
    collector.addSample(e.getResult());
}

public void cleanUp(){
    CustomCollector.cleanUp();
}
}
```

On my Windows server, I add the listener and it works well. I can see the data in the MySQL server. But when I move the script into the Linux and run it with command

```
  nohup ./jmeter -n -t /opt/tests/test.jmx -l /opt/log/perf_result.csv -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.url=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" > /opt/log/jmeter_script_run.out 2> /opt/log/jmeter_script_run.err < /dev/null
```

And I get the error in jmeter.log like:

```
2015/08/08 04:36:28 INFO  - com.test.jmeter.logger.PerformanceResultCollector: construct performance collector
2015/08/08 04:36:28 ERROR - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: java.lang.NullPointerException : java.lang.NullPointerException
---- Debugging information ----
message             : java.lang.NullPointerException
cause-exception     : java.lang.RuntimeException
cause-message       : java.lang.NullPointerException
class               : com.test.jmeter.logger.PerformanceResultCollector
required-type       : com.test.jmeter.logger.PerformanceResultCollector
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/com.test.jmeter.logger.PerformanceResultCollector
line number         : 379
class[1]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
------------------------------- : java.lang.NullPointerException : java.lang.NullPointerException
---- Debugging information ----
message             : java.lang.NullPointerException
cause-exception     : java.lang.RuntimeException
cause-message       : java.lang.NullPointerException
class               : com.test.jmeter.logger.PerformanceResultCollector
required-type       : com.test.jmeter.logger.PerformanceResultCollector
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/com.test.jmeter.logger.PerformanceResultCollector
line number         : 379
class[1]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
```

In the log, I find that it has alreay come into the construct function of PerformanceResultCollector. But why it throw the NulPointerException. I confirm the lib of jmeter on Linux is same as on Windows. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my listener? Many thanks

> 

After I have modified my code many times, I finally know how to resolve it, even through I don't know the reason. In the PerformanceResultCollector.class, if I construct the lazy CustomCollector, it works.

```
public class PerformanceResultCollector extends ResultCollector implements Serializable {    
CustomCollector collector;

public PerformanceResultCollector() {    
  log.info("construct performance collector")

}
@Override
public void sampleOccurred(SampleEvent e) {
if (null == collector) {
    collector = new CustomCollector();
}
collector.addSample(e.getResult());
}

public void cleanUp(){
    CustomCollector.cleanUp();
}
}
```

Maybe the JMeter parses the jmx script in different ways for non-gui and gui mode.

Comment: can you show code of PerformanceResultCollector at line 379 ?

Comment: not sure if it may help , but 2 things to watch out for are the file path separator and line endings.

Comment: @UBIK LOAD PACK  PerformanceResultCollector.class just have 54 lines. The line 379 might be in SaveService.class

Comment: @Clyde D'Cruz  Are the file separator and line endings you mentioned in the Linux command or other java class files.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also put the MySql driver into jmeter/lib folder ?

Are you sure about your jdbc url ? are host:port joinable from your linux machine ?

What does CustomCollector constructor do ?

Did you try on windows in non -gui mode your class or only in gui mode ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just update the question. I think I just know how resolve it, even though I don't know the reason. Maybe the JMeter parses the jmx script in different ways for non-gui and gui mode.

Comment: Hi, it parses it the same way but init is different. You should accept answer if the fix was in constructor as you seem to indicate it.